# How can I search a string for any occurrence of substring (including partial matches) in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a program which will search through a series of strings and return true if any part of a substring is found.

For example, say the substring I am interested in is:

```
GATCGATC
```

The program should return True for:

```
GGTGGATCGATC
```

And should also return true for (because it ends with GATC):

```
GGTGTTTTGATC
```

So far I have:

```
def matchpat(str1, str2):
    '''Find a pattern in a string'''
    if str1 in str2:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

This function works, but only if the whole pattern is present, it will return False for partial matches.

Comment: Partial matches with any threshold in particular? Because a matching letter is also a partial match

Comment: Please clarify your task: "any part of a substring is found" - how big the part should be? Does one letter counts as part of the string? Or do we look at the fact that "GATCGATC" is repeating of "GATC" substring?

Comment: Please post a sample for both `True` and `False` cases.

Comment: So the sentence `This is not working` should also return `TRUE` because it ends with a substring of `GATCGATC`? (The sentence contains the letter `G`, which is a substring of `GATCGATC`)

Comment: Yes, if the string ends with a partial match, even a single G, then it should return True.

Comment: I could make this work though `if string[-7:].endswith(substring[:6]):` over and over again until the whole substring is covered. Although, I feel like there is a much better method.

Comment: But why are you now talking only about endings and therefore `str.endsdwith()`? In your question you explicitely ask for _any_ occurrence of _any_ substring - please clarify and be unambiguous.

Comment: Supplemental: Regarding your call of `endswith` "over and over again until the whole substring is covered": there is of course sth much better: just check if the last single characters match. If they don't match, then the last `n` characters do not match either.

Answer (score 2):

Hi i made this code which works. 
You can change it to be more dynamical with the variables

```
text = 'GGTGGATCGATC'
lookingFor = 'GATCGATC'

def method():
  print('in check')
  if lookingFor in text:
    return true
  else:
    return false

def main():
  method()
  if __name__ == "__main__":
```

If you want to make the method take in input you can pass it in the method definition:

```
def method(text, lookingFor)
```

Comment: A lot of typos in the code, but it works :-).   `def method():`, `True`, `False`, indents below `def`

Answer (score 0):

I have used a library called [Fuzzywuzzy](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy) for a similar problem, which worked well for my requirements and may help.

It uses [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) metric to compare the strings.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but I wanted to try and write the code without importing any modules.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [re module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) to do that

```
import re

patterntomatch = "GATCGATC"
patterntomatch = "[{0}]".format(patterntomatch)

TextTomatch = "This is something"

matchObj = re.match(patterntomatch,TextTomatch,re.I)

if matchObj:
    print ("match found")
else:
    print("no match found")
```